# Xcode - Larger Text on 4 inch iPhones

Tags: iphone, xcode

Right now I'm using a UILabel to create a paragraph of text in my iPhone app. I am not using auto layout, and I set the paragraph to center in the View Controller on 4 inch iPhones. My question is: how would I make it so that the font size would be larger on 4 inch iPhones?

Comment: In my opinion, you shouldn't. When designing your app you should use Dynamic Text by selecting the appropriate font type (i.e. `UIFontTextStyleBody`) in IB. The user can then select the appropriate text size in `Settings->General->Text Size` or `Accessibility` for bold text depending on how large they want the text. Your UILabel should respond to that selection. You should also consider that this year there will be at least 2 more sizes and you should not be hardcoding font sizes for different devices.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll keep this in mind